# nodemon causing crash on restart - spawn EBADF

Tags: node.js, macos, nodemon

While using nodemon to watch my entire project directory and restart on any file changes during development, it always crashes when a file is changed. I can also force it to happen just by typing `rs`. Output below:

```
> ./node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=local nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:95048) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:95048) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Server running on port 8080
(node:95048) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
rs
node:internal/child_process:413
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EBADF
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:689:9)
    at module.exports (/Users/tony/Documents/Node/MILAM/node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/tree.js:8:14)
    at main (/Users/tony/Documents/Node/MILAM/node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/index.js:17:12)
    at kill (/Users/tony/Documents/Node/MILAM/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:344:5)
    at run.kill (/Users/tony/Documents/Node/MILAM/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:265:9)
    at Bus.<anonymous> (/Users/tony/Documents/Node/MILAM/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js:416:7)
    at Bus.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/Users/tony/Documents/Node/MILAM/node_modules/nodemon/lib/nodemon.js:107:15)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:539:35) {
  errno: -9,
  code: 'EBADF',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Node.js v18.2.0
```

Comment: I don't think this errors are caused by `nodemon` . Your app is showing lots of `DeprecationWarnings` , try fixing them and also  there is `ChildProcess` error, i recommend using `PM2` for spawning child processes.

Comment: run your app with `node`  runtime and send that errors if there was any

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia The app runs fine on it's own and even with nodemon. It's only when nodemon restarts that it crashes.